# Formatting the X axis of a graph in Microsoft Report Builder

Tags: reportbuilder

In my report there is a chart showing the success rate of the software distribution. Now the weekends are to be highlighted somehow. Because the report is still relatively new, there were problems with the data collection and days are missing in between. So an interval of 7 does not do it here.

The type of highlighting is not specified. I have thought about displaying the labels in bold or in a color. A vertical line would also be a option.

The values on the X axis are of type Date, so I tried in Horizontal Axis Properties -> Label Font to format the color with an expression:

`=IIF(Weekday(Fields!Timestamp.Value)=1,"Red","Black")`

According to my knowledge of the Weekday function, Sundays should now be displayed in red. But not only that this is not the case, nothing happens at all. What am I missing?

**Update**: I tried the expression that didn't work for the grindlines and labels on the markers and for some reason it works there.

```
=IIF(Weekday(Fields!Timestamp.Value)=1,"Square",IIF(Weekday(Fields!Timestamp.Value)=>7,"Square","None"))
```

For whatever reason. Would still be up for other suggestions.